# Finding the distance between two data points in an org hierarchy using two columns of data in R?

Tags: r, hierarchy, orgchart

For my dataset, I have two columns of data containing employee names and I am trying to the find the distance between two employees in the org's hierarchy. Here's a snippet of what the data looks like:

```
| Employee | Supervisor|
| -------- | --------- |
| Wald, Z  | Holt, K   |
| Kent, P  | Wald, Z   |
| Clark, O | Kent, P   |
```

Is there any code I could write in R to find the distance between `Clark, O` and `Holt, K`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end convert it to a matrix and then to an igraph object.  Now use `distances` to get the distances between every pair of vertices.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(DF))

distances(g)
##          Wald, Z Holt, K Kent, P Clark, O
## Wald, Z        0       1       1        2
## Holt, K        1       0       2        3
## Kent, P        1       2       0        1
## Clark, O       2       3       1        0

set.seed(123)
plot(g)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
Lines <- "Employee | Supervisor
Wald, Z  | Holt, K   
Kent, P  | Wald, Z   
Clark, O | Kent, P   "
DF <- read.table(text = gsub("|", "", Lines), header = TRUE, sep = "|", 
  strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: So my dataframe comes from a CSV file. Is there any way I can do the above by converting that to a matrix and then use igraph?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the additional question above, but if you have a data frame/tibble you can do basically the same thing with the `graph_from_data_frame` function.

```r
library(igraph)

g = graph_from_data_frame(select(data, Employee, Supervisor))
distances(g)
```